# primary and secondary location URI ina storageURI must point to the same resource windows azure

Tags: azure-blob-storage

I am just try to connect my Blob Storage with .net SDK with MVC application and here is my code;

```
 public static CloudBlobClient CreateClient(UnitOfWork uow)
    {
        CloudStorageList credentials;
        CloudBlobClient client;


            credentials = uow.RepositoryFor<CloudStorageList>().GetAll(filter: xx => !xx.IsDeleted).FirstOrDefault();
            var storageCredentials = new StorageCredentials(credentials.Name, credentials.PrimaryAccessKey);    
        var storage =
                new CloudStorageAccount(storageCredentials,true);
        client = storage.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        return client;
    }
```

But I am facing the error when I reached the line;

```
 var storage =
            new CloudStorageAccount(storageCredentials,true);
```

I have just mention the error in the subject i.e. primary and secondear location URI in a storageUI must point to the same resource.

Any help will be a favor.

Regards,

Comment: Which version of Azure Storage Client Library are you using?

Answer (score 0):

var storageCredential = new StorageCredentials(*, **);

- is the account name : this is the name of your storagename
  [image: *]

** is the keyValue : vieuw in the image

[image]